# Remove child element from a JSON array in PHP / codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I am getting below json array as and i want to remove the child node "n":[] - when it is empty. (PHP)

INPUT:

```
[
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "101",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "102",
        "n": [

        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "103",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "104",
        "n": [

        ]
      },
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "105",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "106",
            "n": [

            ]
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "107",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "108",
                "n": [
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "109",
                    "n": [

                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "110",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "111",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "112",
            "n": [

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "113",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "114",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "115",
                "n": [

                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "116",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "117",
                "n": [

                ]
              },
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "118",
                "n": [
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "119",
                    "n": [

                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "120",
                    "n": [

                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "101",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "102"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "103",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "104"
      },
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "105",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "106"
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "107",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "108",
                "n": [
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "109"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "level": 1,
    "id": "110",
    "n": [
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "111",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "112"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "level": 2,
        "id": "113",
        "n": [
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "114",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "115"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "level": 3,
            "id": "116",
            "n": [
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "117"
              },
              {
                "level": 4,
                "id": "118",
                "n": [
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "119"
                  },
                  {
                    "level": 5,
                    "id": "120"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

All the  ,"n":[] removed from the json array.
Please help me with some PHP code to get the output from that above input.

Comment: Please be careful with your formatting. This was, frankly, a mess. Also, if you want to achieve what you want using PHP, don't tag other irrelevant languages, such as jQuery and JS

Comment: Nicely edited @RoryMcCrossan. --- Wouldn't this be a matter of recursively travelling through the object, and removing the empty `n` arrays? What have you tried so far?

Comment: You want to do this in PHP or javascript ? In your code you have javascript objects.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia : I want this in PHP. But I am getting that input from js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the recursion, to recursively find the property `n` which has the value `[]` and delete them:

```js
function removeEmptyNode(nodes) {
  if(!nodes || nodes.length === 0)
    return;
  
  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    if(node.n.length === 0) {
     delete node.n; 
    } else {
      removeEmptyNode(node.n);
    }
  });
}


var data = [{
  "level": 1,
  "id": "101",
  "n": [{
    "level": 2,
    "id": "102",
    "n": []
  }]
}, {
  "level": 1,
  "id": "103",
  "n": [{
    "level": 2,
    "id": "104",
    "n": []
  }, {
    "level": 2,
    "id": "105",
    "n": [{
      "level": 3,
      "id": "106",
      "n": []
    }, {
      "level": 3,
      "id": "107",
      "n": [{
        "level": 4,
        "id": "108",
        "n": [{
          "level": 5,
          "id": "109",
          "n": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "level": 1,
  "id": "110",
  "n": [{
    "level": 2,
    "id": "111",
    "n": [{
      "level": 3,
      "id": "112",
      "n": []
    }]
  }, {
    "level": 2,
    "id": "113",
    "n": [{
      "level": 3,
      "id": "114",
      "n": [{
        "level": 4,
        "id": "115",
        "n": []
      }]
    }, {
      "level": 3,
      "id": "116",
      "n": [{
        "level": 4,
        "id": "117",
        "n": []
      }, {
        "level": 4,
        "id": "118",
        "n": [{
          "level": 5,
          "id": "119",
          "n": []
        }, {
          "level": 5,
          "id": "120",
          "n": []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

removeEmptyNode(data);
console.log(data);
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to do this in PHP, you can convert the above code easily to PHP.
Assuming you have source object in JSON string, you could be able to use this code:

```
<?php

function removeEmptyNodes(&$nodes) {
    if(empty($nodes)) {
        return;
    }

    foreach($nodes as &$node) {
        if(empty($node['n'])) {
            unset($node['n']);
        } else {
            removeEmptyNodes($node['n']);
        }
    }
}

$json = '[{"level":1,"id":"101","n":[{"level":2,"id":"102","n":[]}]},{"level":1,"id":"103","n":[{"level":2,"id":"104","n":[]},{"level":2,"id":"105","n":[{"level":3,"id":"106","n":[]},{"level":3,"id":"107","n":[{"level":4,"id":"108","n":[{"level":5,"id":"109","n":[]}]}]}]}]},{"level":1,"id":"110","n":[{"level":2,"id":"111","n":[{"level":3,"id":"112","n":[]}]},{"level":2,"id":"113","n":[{"level":3,"id":"114","n":[{"level":4,"id":"115","n":[]}]},{"level":3,"id":"116","n":[{"level":4,"id":"117","n":[]},{"level":4,"id":"118","n":[{"level":5,"id":"119","n":[]},{"level":5,"id":"120","n":[]}]}]}]}]}]';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

removeEmptyNodes($data);
print_r(json_encode($data));
?>
```

Comment: plz make this in PHP .